# can i apply L'Hospital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

Can I apply L'Hospital's rule to this. If $A(0)\neq0, B(0)=0, C(0)=0$, and $B(\epsilon), C(\epsilon)$ are differentiable by $\epsilon$, but $A(\epsilon)$ isn't known whether it is differentiable.

$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{A(\epsilon)B(\epsilon)}{C(\epsilon)}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{A(\epsilon)B^\prime(\epsilon)}{C^\prime(\epsilon)}$

Comment: This is certainly not L'Hopital's Rule. You are not even differentiating the numerator.

Comment: Looks like you need to use the Product Rule (but you have not given enough information, so it may not be applicable) and also L'Hopital (but again you have not given enough conditions for it to be applicable).

Comment: If we assume that $A$ is continuous at $0$ and $A(0)\neq 0$ then your limit equals $A(0)\lim_{h\to 0}(B(h)/C(h))$ and one can apply L Hospital's Rule on $B/C$.

Comment: Thinking about it gain, I immediately understood. Thank you.